# Bigmemory package and ff

Tags: r

Any suggestion for dealing with big data with columns of different classes? Big.matrix makes me lose non-integer type columns, so I cannot use it. 
My data contains around 200million cases and 30 variables. I have to run 30 loops and each loop takes more than 20 hours running. Is there any suggestion I can get from you? Any other package I can try? 
Unfortunately ff is not available for R 3.2.0 (or at least I don't seem to get access to it)

My loops consist in assigning values to new variables based on numerical analysis,they  look like this:

```
tol <- 0.01
for (i in 1:length(X$latitude) ){ 
if(abs(X$latitude[i] - 40.759161) <  tol && 
abs(X$latitude[i] - 40.758083) <  tol) 
if(abs(X$longitude[i] - -73.985267) < tol &&
abs(X$longitude[i] - -73.986950) < tol)
{
X$Name[i] <- 1
}
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: can you be more specific about your failure to install `ff`? it looks [fine on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html).  There were some CRAN glitches over the last few days, so (1) try again, (2) tell us about your platform/OS ?

Comment: PS if this is an example of what you need to do, it can be run **much** faster with a vectorized operation, even without invoking `dplyr` or `data.table`.

Comment: e.g. `latlim <- c(40.759161,0.758083); longlim <- c(73.985267,73.986950); x$Name <-with(X,as.numeric(abs(latitude-latlim[1])<tol & abs(latitude-latlim[2])<tol & abs(longitude-longlim[1])<tol & abs(longitude-longlim[2])<tol))`